# RabbitVCS GUI is not working and synced repositories are not being marked in nautilus file browser

Tags: rabbitvcs

I am unable to update, commit or see the changes made to the my project repository. They are not being 'tick' marked. However I can perform all the operations through the command-line/console.

Here is a copy of my rabbitvcs.log file

> ClientError: The node
>   '/home/zubair/Work/Codebase/.../activator-launch-1.3.2/xsbti'
>   was not found. 2016-07-06 19:31:54,683 ERROR  rabbitvcs.vcs.svn   The
>   node
>   '/home/zubair/Work/Codebase/.../activator-launch-1.3.2/xsbt'
>   was not found. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rabbitvcs/vcs/svn/**init**.py", line
>   263, in statuses
>       update=update)

**Tip** : It is working fine when I open the file browser in **sudo** mode

**Note :** I have tried all the solutions mentioned here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/346602/13-04-no-context-menu-after-rabbitvcs-install , but they are not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it was working earlier and suddenly disappeared from the nautilus manager i.e you are no longer able to see the rabbitvcs option on your repository directories, probably you(current user) might not have permissions for it.

Try this:

> sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.config/rabbitvcs

and then re-login to see the changes.

That's it.